# Regular expressions for catching stats and saving them on the fly

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a text file with stats. Each one of them is on a separate line. I go through every line in R and grep it. The stats that I am interested in are of the type seen below:

```
system.l2.precompression_table.entry_0_all_mappings            0                       # all mappings for entry #0
system.l2.precompression_table.entry_0_avg_mappings            0                       # average number of mappings for entry #0
system.l2.precompression_table.entry_10_all_mappings           30                       # all mappings for entry #10
system.l2.precompression_table.entry_10_avg_mappings            4                       # average number of mappings for entry #10
```

The numbers for entries start from 0 and go up to 63.

In other cases, when I'm trying to collect stats that don't have a certain pattern I'm doing something like this.

```
if (grepl("final_tick", line))
  {
    matches <- regmatches(line, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", line))
    final_tick = as.numeric(unlist(matches))[1]
  }
```

I want to do something similar but not have as many if statements as the number of stats. I want to have a grep statement that uses a regular expression to find stats that are like "entry_num_###_mappings" and save it to a data frame with the name of the stat on one column while the other column has the numeric value. (The regular expression can catch any stat that starts with entry and finishes with mappings. The type of mappings (all/avg) may change).

Something like that:

```
df
stat                  | value
entry_10_all_mappings    30
entry_10_avg_mappings     4
```

Comment: just read in the data as a datatable then use `sub('.*[.]','',df[,1])` to create a new variable for `stat`

Answer (score 0):

Using the package `stringr`, you can do:

```
library(stringr)

# Select any line containing "entry_num_all_mappings" or "entry_num_avg_mappings":
selection <- readLines("data.txt") %>%
  str_subset("entry_\\d+_a.._mappings")

# Extract the "stat" part
stat <- selection %>%
  str_extract("entry_\\d+_a.._mappings")

# Extract the "value" part
value <- selection %>%
  str_extract(" \\d+ ") %>%
  trimws()

# Create your data frame
df <- data.frame(stat, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the text file using `read.table` in a dataframe

```
df <- read.table("name_of_text_file.txt")
```

Select all the rows which follow the pattern required

```
df1 <- df[grepl("entry_\\d+_(avg|all)_mappings", df$V1), ]
```

Create a new column (if needed) with the pattern

```
df1$V3 <- sub(".*(entry_\\d+_(avg|all)_mapping)", "\\1", df1$V1)
```

Comment: Nice one. I like the use of `read.table`! It will break if any line in the OP's text file does not have 2 elements though (but there is nothing in the info provided that indicates that it may be the case).